# Queue management & predictions with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, queue

I'm building a restaurant-management app with Rails, and I'm a little stuck when it comes to predicting when tables might open up for guests on a waitlist.

**A typical example:** if we make it easy and assume there are 10 one-person tables in the restaurant, and that they're all occupied right now, and there are 10 individual diners on the waitlist, how long will the eleventh person have to wait for his table if we can assume each diner will stay for 30 minutes?

**I'm not looking for actual code for this sort of problem,* but I'd appreciate advice about things to look at/consider.**

Is this some sort of FIFO queue?  Should I be looking at set theory?  Network theory?  Are there any stdlibs that are helpful in building out a system like this?

**Thanks in advance for your help!**

*but if there's relevant code out there, I'd of course be happy to see it!

Answer (score 1):

You could create Table model. This model has a flag(boolean) - occupied and free. Every time when a customer occupied and released the table a system should change this flag accordingly. This functionality will automatically change `updated_at` time in database. So in case the table is occupied then the release time will be `updated_at + 30` minutes. Next you can ask all tables to calculate the nearest time of releasing the table.

Comment: Aha!  What you're proposing is kind of obvious :-P, and it's what I was planning, schema-wise, but seeing it written out gave me insight into how to perhaps handle longer-term predictions: The _next_ available table is just the first-updated occupied table, and like you said, it'll be available in `updated_at+30 minutes`.  If there are 3 people ahead of the person in the queue, their wait is `updated_at + 30 minutes` of the fourth person in this sorted list of occupied tables....

Comment: now I just need to think about predicting the wait time if there are more people waiting than there are tables....